# Passing Arrays of any size to C++ functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, parameter-passing

I know that you can pass arrays in other ways such as:

> returnType functionName (dataType array[][10])

But I am interested in case where you don't know the size of the array in advance. I want to be able to pass the number of rows and number of columns as parameters.

How do i pass an array of any size to a C++ function? I want to do something along the lines of :

```
void functionName(dataType array[][], int num_rows, int num_cols){
   // ***Some operation such as printing the array's contents***
}
```

Comment: returnType functionName (dataType array[][10])- this is not the way passing an array

Comment: Anyway, arrays have no rows or columns...

Comment: @skypjack yes they do. 2D arrays are arrays and 2D arrays have rows and columns, put 2 and 2 together....if you cant answer the question, don't bother commenting bro

Comment: You could try `returnType functionName(dataType** array, int rows, int cols)`

Comment: Pass (pointer to the first element, row size, column size) as parameters

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz I tried that but it wouldn't work. Does that work for you?

Comment: Why it did not work? What is the error?

Comment: @Giggs As you want. You'll learn it sooner or later. No problem my side.

Comment: @Giggs, ok, works for me. Not every construct is fit to a specific purpose. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways to go about this:

1. You pass pointer to the first element with row and column size as the parameters.
2. If array size is known at compile-time, you can use templates. Something like:

`template <std::size_t W, std::size_t H> void func(Type (&array)[W][H]) {}`

3. You use a 2D vector and pass it into the function. But it's not so efficient if you don't need to resize separate columns.

Comment: 2D vector would be an overkill if you don't need to resize a separate columns. For a simple 2D array I would use the first option. One can also use something template-based if array size is known at compile time.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat How would one go about the template-based option?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm looking exactly for something along those lines. I tried to implement the function with the signature above but it wouldn't work. Could you show me an example implementation that, for example, prints out the contents of a 2D INT array. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you very much! One last question, I noticed you are passing the array by reference, but because an array is really a pass by pointer, is that really necessary?
Secondly, I tried calling the function in the following way: func<4,4>(anArray) for a 4 X 4 array. How is your implementation of the function inferring the values of W and H. Thanks again!

Comment: @Giggs Yep it is. If you try to *just* make an array argument, then the argument type will be converted to pointer, which will remove information about the array size (example: `void f(int a[3])` accepts an array of any size and there is no way to get the size). Because of this you need to use pointer to *an entire array* (`void f(int (*a)[3])`) or reference to an entire array (`void f(int (&a)[3])`). There is no big difference, but the second option is more convenient because you don't need that extra dereferencing operator.

Comment: @Giggs *"How is your implementation of the function inferring the values of W and H."* - It is called *template argument deduction*. If you omit template arguments `<>`, the compiler will guess them for you. If it's unable to guess them, it will yell at you with error.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you! You're answers were the best!

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

1. Use a vector of vectors, then you won't even have to pass the sizes as extra arguments:

   `void functionName( std::vector<std::vector<dataType>>);`
2. Use a one-dimensional array that emulates a two-dimensional one:

   `void functionName( dataType [] array, int num_rows, int num_cols);`

Calculate the index of the one-dimensional array like this:

```
int i = row_index * num_cols + column_index;
```

Comment: yeah I know there are alternatives and ways to circumvent the issue, I was just wondering if there was a way to properly do it. Like in the one dimensional array case.